# Help analysing Mean Residual Life Plot for GPD

Tags: data-visualization, extreme-value, pareto-distribution

I'm trying to fit a GPD for a set of time dependant data. I have two columns, data which is a value on the negative real line where values closest to zero are considered extremes, and time. Using only the data column I've used the ismev package to produce a MRL plot but the plot doesn't look like any MRL plot I'm used to seeing.

I'm very new to the field of EVT and any help trying to determine my threshold or issues with my methodology would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you use flexsurv to estimate your survival model, you can use the new “reslife” package to get the MRL.
Disclaimer: I helped create the “reslife” package.

Comment: In *Extreme Value Theory* (EVT) the upper end-point of the distribution is usually unknown and most models allow it to be finite or not. To better conform to this practice you may have to transform the variable e.g. taking the negated inverse using$x \mapsto -1/x$.